# Spring + Kotlin + itextpdf

Tags: spring, kotlin, itext

```
package com.cmn.dt.event.service
import com.cmn.dt.event.dto.EventResponseDto
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream

@Service
class GenerateFDS {
   
    fun eventReport(event: EventResponseDto): ByteArrayInputStream {
        val document = Document()
        val out = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out)
        document.open()

        val reader = PdfReader("FDS.pdf")
        PdfWriter.getImportedPage(reader,1)
```

I have this error

> GenerateFDS.kt: (40, 38): Unresolved reference: getImportedPage

I don't understand why. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you need to instantiate object of `PdfWriter` and then call the method on the intstance.

Comment: Thanks, it's ok now.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun eventReport(event: EventResponseDto): ByteArrayInputStream {
    val document = Document()
    val out = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out)
    document.open()
    val reader = PdfReader("FDS.pdf")
    val imported = writer.getImportedPage(reader,1)
```

That's ok with this code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).